# When I start Cassandra server, two processes start running. Is this normal?

Tags: cassandra

When I start Cassandra server, two processes start running.
Is this the normal behavior of Cassandra?
Below is the result set with two different process IDs:

```
5362 jsvc.exec -user cassandra -home /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/../ -pidfile /var/run/cassandra.pid -errfile &1 -outfile /var/log/cassandra/output.log -cp /usr/share/cassandra/lib/antlr-3.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/avro-1.4.0-fixes.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/avro-1.4.0-sources-fixes.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-codec-1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/guava-r08.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/high-scale-lib-1.1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/libthrift-0.7.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/metrics-core-2.0.3.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snakeyaml-1.6.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snaptree-0.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-1.1.5.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-thrift-1.1.5.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/stress.jar:/usr/share/java/jna.jar:/etc/cassandra:/usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-server.properties -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/lib/cassandra/java_1351664352.hprof -XX:ErrorFile=/var/lib/cassandra/hs_err_1351664352.log -ea -javaagent:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -Xmn256M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss160k -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7199 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraDaemon
5363 jsvc.exec -user cassandra -home /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/../ -pidfile /var/run/cassandra.pid -errfile &1 -outfile /var/log/cassandra/output.log -cp /usr/share/cassandra/lib/antlr-3.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/avro-1.4.0-fixes.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/avro-1.4.0-sources-fixes.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-codec-1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/guava-r08.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/high-scale-lib-1.1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/libthrift-0.7.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/metrics-core-2.0.3.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snakeyaml-1.6.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snaptree-0.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-1.1.5.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-thrift-1.1.5.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/stress.jar:/usr/share/java/jna.jar:/etc/cassandra:/usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-server.properties -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/lib/cassandra/java_1351664352.hprof -XX:ErrorFile=/var/lib/cassandra/hs_err_1351664352.log -ea -javaagent:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -Xmn256M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss160k -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7199 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraDaemon
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is normal.  We use jsvc to daemonize cleanly.